# How to create timer score for pong in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple pong game in codeskulptor i have made it so the AI never loses and the speed keeps increasing by 10 percent, therefore it becomes a survival game, instead of their being a scoring system, i want there to be an accelerated timer, always increasing as the ball increases and your score to be what you get at the end of the timer, How would i go about creating the timer, what would i need to look into? Are timers in other languages simler to coding in python/

Here's the code give your insight. It would be much appreciated
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user43_dbsE9UqFhx_1.py

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! Unfortunately, this question seems like a "gimme teh codez" question. SO is not a code writing service; see [ask] and take a look at the [tour].

Comment: no i dont want the code, i want to know the theory behind it, so i can figure out a way to implement it, so for e.g. the maths behind the timer or if there is a function in python to resemble a timer, if that makes sense

Comment: Even then, it would still have code in it, and we do not want our efforts wasted from people who go and copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your game loop, write a small function that checks the time (using pythons time package) every iteration (or every 3 or 4 iterations, since every iteration would be overkill). Subtract that from the time at the last iteration, then add that new value to your total time. That'll tell you how much time has passed. Now all you have to do is output that to the screen